# Cargo fails to find a creat that is declared on toml and also exists?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, dependencies, rust-cargo

So I have this toml on a large project:

```ini
[package]
name = "semperengine"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "semperengine"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[dependencies]
rand_pcg = "0.3.1"
rand = "0.8.5"
image = "0.24.3"
cfg-if = "1.0.0"

# internal
algebra = { path = "crates/algebra" }
builder = { path = "crates/builder" }
camera = { path = "crates/camera" }
chicken_wire = { path = "crates/chicken_wire" }
dual_contouring = { path = "crates/dual_contouring/" }
geometry = { path = "crates/geometry" }
hedge = { path = "crates/hedge" }
iterators = { path = "crates/iterators" }
ne_core = { path = "crates/ne_core" }
ne_gui = { path = "crates/ne_gui" }
noise = { path = "crates/noise" }
numerical_analysis = { path = "crates/numerical_analysis" }
peripherals = { path = "crates/peripherals" }
pga = { path = "crates/pga" }
topology = { path = "crates/topology" }
thread_pool = { path = "crates/thread_pool" }
vulkan_bindings = { path = "crates/vulkan_bindings" }
```

When I run cargo buld I get this:

```
error: no matching package named `thread_pool` found
location searched: /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/thread_pool
required by package `semperengine v0.1.0 (/home/makogan/rust_never_engine)`
```

But the crate exists:

```bash
ls /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/thread_pool/
benches  Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  flamegraph.svg  out.txt  perf.data  perf.data.old  src  target
```

Why can't cargo find that specific crate when it can find all the others?

Answer (score 1):

This happened because the crate `thread_pool` used to be called `experimental_thread_pool`. Upon refactoring the `Cargo.toml` file of `thread_pool` still had:

```
[package]
name = "experimental_thread_pool"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
```

Correcting it to

```
[package]
name = "thread_pool"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
```

Fixed the problem.